# .pack_forget() not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am have problems with `.pack_forget()` function. If I write:

```
a1= Button(root, text='button', width=10, command=buttonclick).pack()
```

function `a1.pack_forget()` returns error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack_forget'
```

But if I write:

```
a1= Button(root, text='button', width=10, command=buttonclick)
a1.pack()
```

function `a1.pack_forget()` works properly. Why does shorter way not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, when you do `x=foo().bar()`, `x` is given the value of `bar()`. So, in the case of `ai=Button(...).pack(...)`, `ai` gets the value of `pack(...)`.

With tkinter, `pack(...)` and `grid(...)` and `place(...)` all return `None`. Thus, in your code `ai` is set to `None`. That's how tkinter and python have been designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

The method `pack()` returns `None`. You have to write:

```
ai = Button(...)
ai.pack()
```

The first line assigns a `Button` object to the variable `ai`, while something like

```
ai = Button(...).pack()
```

would assign it to `None`.